# How to build javascript array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of objects that I return using webservice. And I try to build an array like you can see below.

```
$.each(items, function (index, item) {                           
    i[index] = '[' + item.Name + ',' + item.Count + ']';                            
});
```

I need to build array like

```
var t = [['Mushrooms', 3], ['Onions', 1], ['Olives', 1], ['Zucchini', 1], ['Pepperoni', 2], ];
```

but it's not working for me for some reason. It should not be string. It needs to has the same format as you see in example. Otherwise it will not work.

Here is the rest of the code I need to add it to table

```
var t = [['High', 3], ['Onions', 1], ['Olives', 1], ['Zucchini', 1], ['Pepperoni', 2], ];

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows(t);
```

Comment: Is `i` an Array, or a String?

Comment: Excellent article on this subject here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use quotes:

```
var t = [];
$.each(items, function (index, item) {                           
    t[index] = [item.Name, item.Count];                            
});
```

I also added the code to initialize `t` (assuming you want that instead of `i`).

Comment: I need to build exact like you see in example. Otherwise it's not working, just replace names and count var t = [['Mushrooms', 3], ['Onions', 1], ['Olives', 1], ['Zucchini', 1], ['Pepperoni', 2], ];

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(items, function (index, item) {                           
    i.push([item.Name, item.Count]);                            
});
```

remove the `'` characters and you will be an actual array.